# Run a PHP script every second for all users

Tags: php, mysql

I know there are several questions on SO with that kind of title, but none seems to have helped me so far.

I'm making a browser game in jQuery / Ajax / PHP where I want to create a NPC that has a specific pathfinding that loops (for example, 5 steps down, 5 right, 5 up and 5 left). But any connected player should see this NPC at its current position anytime, that's why I need to store the current X and Y position of the NPC in the database. The NPC makes a step every second.

I tried something like this :

index.php :

```
function loopNPC(){

    $(document).load('getNPC.php', function(npc){
        $('.npc').remove();       // I remove the NPC's image with previous position
        $('.map').append(npc);    // I add the new one
    });

}

setInterval(loopNPC, 1000);
```

and in the getNPC.php file, I have something like this :

```
<?php
/* Here I have a string like this : "dddddrrrrruuuuulllll" where "d" : down,
"r" : right, etc. And I check the characters of this string one after
another every second this script is called in index.php */   

// I store the new NPC position in the database :

$newNPC = $db->prepare('update npc set x = :x, y = :y, map = :map where id = :id');
$newNPC->execute(array(
        'x' => $posX,
        'y' => $posY,
        'map' => $map,
        'id' => $row['id']
        ));

// and here I just "echo" the image of the NPC with its new X and Y positions, 
// which I append to $('.map') in the index.php code
```

It works fine when I'm the only connected player, but I tried creating and connecting another player on a different browser to simulate two sessions connected to the game simultaneously, and now the NPC moves twice faster (not 1 step / second, but 2) just because that second session also calls this PHP script every second.

Is there a way to make an "UPDATE" SQL query to the database every second without it being duplicated when a new player / session is connected ? Like a script that would run every second whatever the number of connected users ?

I've heard of cron jobs but I'm not sure that's what I'm looking for

Thank you

Comment: The current code 'does action on request'; there is nothing there explicitly linked to time. If you do want to do this (I would not use SQL as such is not needed when using a persistent service), then run a *persisted [PHP] 'game engine' service* that performs the action(s) every second (eg. with a loop and timing), *independent* of how many requests there may be - a PHP website will then *proxy* to this always-running/always-updating service.

Comment: It may also be worthwhile to look into Web Sockets or long-polling / COMET.

Comment: To expand on @user2864740's point, what happens if there are no players connected, does the world freeze? A game engine has very specific requirements (resources, scheduling, backing up state, etc...) that don't translate well to web architecture. Of course, the client-server model has benefits for connecting clients, so the best approach is a hybrid. A Long-running server-side process that maintains the game state and a website that queries the current state and displays it to users.

Comment: (To help with the game service itself, consider something like https://github.com/reactphp/react or similar - eg. timed event handling and a way to deal with requests from the front-end.)

Comment: Yeah, with this approach it's unreachable that type of behavior or at least, without it being nightmarish

Comment: Thanks for your answers. "what happens if there are no players connected, does the world freeze? " - basically yes, that's what happens at the moment. Yours and user2864740's solutions are probably the best solution and what I'm looking for, although I'm still new to this world. I just started this game to learn jQuery / Ajax. I will search more about all these alternatives :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not functional for a request/response way with PHP.

You should consider other options, either have a PHP CLI application running on the server side, or use other option for your "game server" like NodeJS, and also consider websockets for the communication instead of normal GET/POST requests.

Websockets allows you to have a constant communication both ways between the client and the server, and then an actual server side application would allow you to keep those communications going and act on them.

Comment: YES ! Thank you, I managed to do it with PHP CLI (just a .bat file running my script in which I added a while (1) {...} loop).